# References for "Capturing value"

Tags: reference-request, utility, markets, value

I have seen in several places references to "capturing value". For example:

- [Value Creation vs. Value Capture](http://svpg.com/value-creation-vs-value-capture/)
- [Work on Stuff that Matters: First Principles](http://radar.oreilly.com/2009/01/work-on-stuff-that-matters-fir.html)

I think that such considerations are particularly useful. For example digital rights management (DRM) does not create any value, it is there to ensure capturing some value. We may discuss whether that is good, bad, necessary or useless, but the concept of "capturing value" is very useful to describe this and much more.

The question is: Has this concept been properly defined in some "citable" reference? (a book, a journal paper, a conference paper, or similar)

As much as I consider it a very interesting and useful concept, it looks like few people are aware of it and providing links as the previous ones may help to understand what it means but they are not particularly descriptive on this concept. To me, the concept is obvious and correct (or so I think) but other people have problems grasping it (or perhaps they refuse to consider its validity without proper definitions). Therefore I would be interested in more reputed, rigorous or explanatory (better if all three) sources.

Comment: Perhaps Marx's use of *surplus value* would be a good early citation and definition. Probably not rigorous in the way of modern economics, and Marx has a reputation for being unclear, but many would accept it as an academically reputable source.

Comment: Both concepts are unrelated.